# Getting argument type mismtach error for @Recover annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-retry, recover

I have a method with below definition

```
    @Retryable(value = {
            APICallFailedException.class,
            IOException.class}, maxAttempts = TransformerConstants.GET_API_MAX_ATTEMPTS, backoff = @Backoff(delay = TransformerConstants.DELAY))
        public <T> T getAPIResponse(String url, Class<T> classType)
```

where APICallFailedException.class extends Runtime exception class

I have a recover method that gets called when all retry attempts fail. It has the following definition

```
    @Recover
        public <T> T getBackendResponseFallback(RuntimeException exception, String getAPIURL,
            Class<T> classType)
```

I changed the method definition of both the methods by adding a String parameter at the end so now they look like

```
     @Retryable(value = {
               APICallFailedException.class,
               IOException.class}, maxAttempts = TransformerConstants.GET_API_MAX_ATTEMPTS, backoff = @Backoff(delay = TransformerConstants.DELAY))
                public <T> T getAPIResponse(String url, Class<T> classType, **String APIUrl**)
        
    
         @Recover
                public <T> T getBackendResponseFallback(RuntimeException exception, String getAPIURL,
                Class<T> classType, **String apiURL**)
```

After doing this when the retryable method fails and recover is called Argument mismatch exception is thrown

Below is the stacktrace

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
               at org.springframework.retry.annotation.RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler.recover(RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler.java:73)
               at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$ItemRecovererCallback.recover(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:141)
               at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512)
               at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351)
               at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
               at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:115)
               at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
               at com.kroger.cxp.app.transformer.util.RestClientUtil$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6079045e.getAPIResponse(<generated>)
```

I want to understand why this is happening. Sprning doc says in @Recover  best matching method is chosen based on the type of the first parameter and the type of the exception being handled. The closest match in the class hierarchy is chosen, so for instance if an IllegalArgumentException is being handled and there is a method whose first argument is RuntimeException, then it will be preferred over a method whose first argument is Throwable

**getAPIResponse** method calls another method inside it with definition

```
    private HttpResponse<byte[]> callAPI(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, String url, Request request)
```

Is it possible that after adding the string parameter in Recover method parameter It tries to match with the second API call i.e callAPI instead of the intended one getAPIResponse

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me with your code; can you provide more details?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So68724467Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68724467Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(foo.getAPIResponse("foo", Object.class, "bar"));
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Retryable(value = {
            IllegalStateException.class,
            IOException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
    public <T> T getAPIResponse(String url, Class<T> classType, String APIUrl) {
        System.out.println("Retryable");
        throw new IllegalStateException("test");
    }

    @Recover
    public <T> T getBackendResponseFallback(RuntimeException exception, String getAPIURL,
            Class<T> classType, String apiUR) {

        System.out.println("Recover");
        return (T) new Object();
    }

}
```